# How to write pseudo code for traversing multi dimensional arrays and how to reference a array instance in pseudo-code?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am new to pseudo-code and have been looking for a reference for a multidimensional array traversal in pseudo-code. All the examples I found were simples ones without the use of arrays. Could someone help me with how to write a pseudocode for the given code snippet?

```
 for i in range(len(temp)-1, -1, -1): 
        myvars1 =[]
        myvars2 = []
        myval1 = 0
        myval2 = 0
        
        for k in range(len(Identifiers_Output)-1, -1, -1):  
            if(temp[i][2]!='fu' and Identifiers_Output[k][1]==temp[i][0] and Identifiers_Output[k][0]<=int(endline) and Identifiers_Output[k][0]<temp[i][1] and Identifiers_Output[k][0] not in Final_Slice):
                line = Identifiers_Output[k][0]
                if(Identifiers_Output[k][2] =='du'):
                    myvars1.append(line)
                    Slice.append(Identifiers_Output[k][0])
                elif(Identifiers_Output[k][2] =='defined'):
                    myvars2.append(line)
                    c=c+1
```

The structure of temp and Identifiers_Output are as per following format:

```
[[2, 'sum', 'defined'], [3, 'i', 'defined'], [4, 'i', 'used'], [5, 'i','used'], [5, 'sum', 'defined'], [6, 'i', 'du'], [6, 'i', 'du'],[7, 'sum', 'used'], [8, 'i', 'used']]
```

As per the pseudocode syntax, how do I reference an array instance such as Identifiers_Output[k][2]

Answer (score 0):

There is not one single standard for pseudo-code that I'm aware of. The aim of writing pseudo-code in the first place is to write something code-like, but without worrying about technical details, to describe an algorithm. By definition, pseudo-code needs to be pretty close to an actual source-code, that is, a professional reading a pseudo-code should not have difficulty in writing the actual code based on the pseudo-code. So, if the syntax of your pseudo-code is pretty close to the actual syntax of the language you intend to implement your code in, the better, because, in that case a programmer can paste a pseudo-code into the appropriate place in the source-code, make a few adjustments and the code is implemented.

Now, taking all this into account, there are MANY programming languages, all with different syntax. You can divide them into large categories, like:

- hierarchical structural languages (SQL languages, XML)
- procedural languages (C)
- rule languages (CSS)
- object-oriented languages (C++, Java, Python, C#, Visual Basic, PHP)
- scripting languages (Javascript)

Or you can group the languages based on syntactical similarities. However you think about languages, ultimately you will surely conclude that you want to write pseudo-code for very different languages very differently. If you aim to implement Python code ultimately, then think Python while you write your pseudo-code.

It's important to be consistent though. So, if you have written a loop, then you should write a similar loop similarly. Take a look at Damian T. Gordon's videos about pseudo-code to grasp some general ideas. Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qg0eYYWjJyY